# How to convert the ADC/PDB part code of Teensy 3.2 for Teensy 4.0

Tags: code, teensy

I was working on two thumb ECG device on Teensy 3.2 but Teensy 3.2 was out of stock everywhere, so I was having only option to buy Teensy 4.0, now I was having code for Teensy 3.2, the below code is not working on teensy 4.0,

Thumb's BioPotential-> Amplify -> Denoise -> Show in LCD -> Detect Abnoraml/Normal ECG

I tried a lot to convert the below code but failed.

[image]

[image]

It would be great you help me regarding this, if not complete code then from resources, It would be great
Thank You

ERR I'm getting:

```
ECG4:593: error: 'PDB_SC_CONT' was not declared in this scope
   | PDB_SC_CONT | PDB_SC_PRESCALER(7) | PDB_SC_MULT(1))
     ^
D:\Documents\Arduino\ECG4\ECG4.ino:606:13: note: in expansion of macro 'PDB_CONFIG'
   PDB0_SC = PDB_CONFIG | PDB_SC_LDOK;
             ^
ECG4:593: error: 'PDB_SC_PRESCALER' was not declared in this scope
   | PDB_SC_CONT | PDB_SC_PRESCALER(7) | PDB_SC_MULT(1))
                                     ^
D:\Documents\Arduino\ECG4\ECG4.ino:606:13: note: in expansion of macro 'PDB_CONFIG'
   PDB0_SC = PDB_CONFIG | PDB_SC_LDOK;
             ^
ECG4:593: error: 'PDB_SC_MULT' was not declared in this scope
   | PDB_SC_CONT | PDB_SC_PRESCALER(7) | PDB_SC_MULT(1))
                                                      ^
D:\Documents\Arduino\ECG4\ECG4.ino:606:13: note: in expansion of macro 'PDB_CONFIG'
   PDB0_SC = PDB_CONFIG | PDB_SC_LDOK;
             ^
ECG4:606: error: 'PDB_SC_LDOK' was not declared in this scope
   PDB0_SC = PDB_CONFIG | PDB_SC_LDOK;
                          ^
ECG4:608: error: 'PDB_SC_SWTRIG' was not declared in this scope
   PDB0_SC |= PDB_SC_SWTRIG;
              ^
ECG4: In function 'void adc0_isr()':
ECG4:615: error: 'ADC0_RA' was not declared in this scope
   LowPass.input(ADC0_RA);
                 ^
Using library SD at version 2.0.0 in folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\teensy\avr\libraries\SD 
Using library SdFat at version 2.1.0 in folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\teensy\avr\libraries\SdFat 
Using library SPI at version 1.0 in folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\teensy\avr\libraries\SPI 
Using library Filters-master at version 0.1.1 in folder: D:\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Filters-master 
Using library SoftwareSerial at version 1.0 in folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\teensy\avr\libraries\SoftwareSerial 
Using library Adafruit_BluefruitLE_nRF51 at version 1.10.0 in folder: D:\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_BluefruitLE_nRF51 
Using library ILI9341_t3 at version 1.0 in folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\teensy\avr\libraries\ILI9341_t3 
'ADC0_CFG1' was not declared in this scope
```

Code:

```
/* ADCpdbDMA
PDB triggers the ADC which requests the DMA to move the data to a buffer
*/
#include <SD.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Filters.h>
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#if not defined (_VARIANT_ARDUINO_DUE_X_) && not defined (_VARIANT_ARDUINO_ZERO_)
  #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#endif
#include "Adafruit_BLE.h"
#include "Adafruit_BluefruitLE_SPI.h"
#include "Adafruit_BluefruitLE_UART.h"
#include "ILI9341_t3.h"

// COMMON SETTINGS
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// These settings are used in both SW UART, HW UART and SPI mode
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#define BUFSIZE                        128   // Size of the read buffer for incoming data
#define VERBOSE_MODE                   true  // If set to 'true' enables debug output


// SOFTWARE UART SETTINGS
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// The following macros declare the pins that will be used for 'SW' serial.
// You should use this option if you are connecting the UART Friend to an UNO
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#define BLUEFRUIT_SWUART_RXD_PIN       9    // Required for software serial!
#define BLUEFRUIT_SWUART_TXD_PIN       10   // Required for software serial!
#define BLUEFRUIT_UART_CTS_PIN         11   // Required for software serial!
#define BLUEFRUIT_UART_RTS_PIN         8    // Optional, set to -1 if unused


// HARDWARE UART SETTINGS
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// The following macros declare the HW serial port you are using. Uncomment
// this line if you are connecting the BLE to Leonardo/Micro or Flora
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifdef Serial1    // this makes it not complain on compilation if there's no Serial1
  #define BLUEFRUIT_HWSERIAL_NAME      Serial1
#endif


// SHARED UART SETTINGS
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// The following sets the optional Mode pin, its recommended but not required
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#define BLUEFRUIT_UART_MODE_PIN        12    // Set to -1 if unused


// SHARED SPI SETTINGS
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// The following macros declare the pins to use for HW and SW SPI communication.
// SCK, MISO and MOSI should be connected to the HW SPI pins on the Uno when
// using HW SPI.  This should be used with nRF51822 based Bluefruit LE modules
// that use SPI (Bluefruit LE SPI Friend).
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#define BLUEFRUIT_SPI_CS               8
#define BLUEFRUIT_SPI_IRQ              7
#define BLUEFRUIT_SPI_RST              4    // Optional but recommended, set to -1 if unused

// SOFTWARE SPI SETTINGS
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// The following macros declare the pins to use for SW SPI communication.
// This should be used with nRF51822 based Bluefruit LE modules that use SPI
// (Bluefruit LE SPI Friend).
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#define BLUEFRUIT_SPI_SCK              13
#define BLUEFRUIT_SPI_MISO             12
#define BLUEFRUIT_SPI_MOSI             11

// For the Adafruit shield, these are the default.
#define TFT_DC 9
#define TFT_CS 10
#define SD_CS 15
#define PDB_CH0C1_TOS 0x0100
#define PDB_CH0C1_EN 0x01

uint16_t buf[7500];
const int pausePin = 2;
const int ReadPin = 3;
const int PupPin = 4;
const int PdownPin = 5;
int bufIndex;
int k;
int pauseState;
int pauseTemp;
bool pause;
int ReadState;
int ReadTemp;
bool Read;
int PupState;
int PupTemp;
bool Pup;
int PdownState;
int PdownTemp;
bool Pdown;
int currentFile;
long int PrevTime;
bool refresh;
long Btemp;
long Ttemp;
long Qtemp;
long rise;
long int QRS;
long HRindex;
long HR[5]{0,0,0,0,0};
uint16_t x;
uint16_t xPrev;
bool stable;
bool stabilizing = false;
bool RiseDetect;
bool drawFinish;
long Arrhythmia[5];

// Use hardware SPI (on Uno, #13, #12, #11) and the above for CS/DC
ILI9341_t3 tft = ILI9341_t3(TFT_CS, TFT_DC);
FilterOnePole LowPass(LOWPASS,7.0);
FilterOnePole HighPass(HIGHPASS, 0.001);
Adafruit_BluefruitLE_SPI ble(BLUEFRUIT_SPI_CS, BLUEFRUIT_SPI_IRQ, BLUEFRUIT_SPI_RST);
int32_t hrmServiceId;
int32_t hrmMeasureCharId;
int32_t hrmLocationCharId;

void error(const __FlashStringHelper*err) {
  Serial.println(err);
  while (1);
}

void setup() {
  // Setting up default value for global variables
  pause = false;
  refresh = false;
  pinMode(pausePin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(ReadPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(PupPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(PdownPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  bufIndex = 0;
  k = 0;
  x = 0;
  xPrev = 0;
  Btemp = 0;
  Ttemp = 0;
  rise = 0;
  stable = true;
  HRindex = 0;
  currentFile = 1;
  RiseDetect = false;
  drawFinish = true;

  // Initializing serial monitor and LCD screen
  Serial.begin(11520);
  tft.begin();
  tft.fillScreen(ILI9341_GREEN);
  while (!Serial); // wait until the serial debug window is opened
  Serial.print("Initializing SD card..."); // Initializing SD card
  if (!SD.begin(SD_CS)) {
    Serial.println("failed!");
  } else {
    Serial.println("OK!");
  }
  bluetoothInit();
  screenInit();
  adcInit();
  pdbInit();
  PrevTime = millis();
}

void loop() {
  pauseState = digitalRead(pausePin);
  if (!pauseState && pauseTemp){
    pause = !pause;
  }
  ReadState = digitalRead(ReadPin);
  if (!ReadState && ReadTemp){
    Read = !Read;
    tft.fillScreen(ILI9341_YELLOW);
    tft.setCursor(20, 150);
    tft.setTextSize(2);
    tft.setTextColor(ILI9341_BLACK);
    tft.print("Mode Changed");
    delay(800);
    screenInit();
    drawFinish = true;
  }
  PupState = digitalRead(PupPin);
  PdownState = digitalRead(PdownPin);
  if(Read) {
    if(drawFinish) {
      readFromFile();
      drawFinish = false;
    }
    x = buf[bufIndex];
    if(k < 320) {
      k++;
    } else {
      k = 0;
    }
    ECG();
    if(bufIndex == 7500) {
      drawFinish = true;
      bufIndex = 0;
    }
    PrevTime = millis();
    pauseTemp = pauseState;
    ReadTemp = ReadState;
  }else{
    ifStable();
    ECG();
    pauseTemp = pauseState;
    ReadTemp = ReadState;
    bluetoothSend(HR[4]);
    writeSD();
    buf[bufIndex] = x;
  }
  long int delayT = millis();
  while(millis() - delayT < 4);
}

void buttonStateChange(int state, int temp, int pin, bool control){
  state = digitalRead(pin);
    if (state && temp){
    control = !control;
  }
}

void screenInit(){
  // Drawing Grid for display
  tft.fillScreen(ILI9341_WHITE);
  tft.setRotation(3);
  cleanScreen();
  tft.fillRect(0, 120, 320, 120, ILI9341_BLACK);
  printHR(0);
  printQRS(0);
}

void cleanScreen() {
  int i, j;
  tft.fillRect(0, 0, 320, 120, ILI9341_WHITE);
  for (i=0; i<340; i+=10) {
    tft.drawLine(i, 0, i, 120, ILI9341_RED);
  }
  for (j=0; j<120; j+=10) {
    tft.drawLine(0, j, 340, j, ILI9341_RED);
  }
}

void ECG() {
  if (!pause && stable) {
    tft.setRotation(3);
    bufIndex = bufIndex % 7500;

    if (k == 320) {
      refresh = true;
      cleanScreen();
      refresh = false;
      k = 0;
    }
    if (x/20+10 > 120) {
      x = 2200;
    }
 
    tft.drawLine(k, xPrev/20+10, k+1, x/20+10, ILI9341_BLACK);
    tft.drawLine(k, xPrev/20+9, k+1, x/20+9, ILI9341_BLACK);

     
    if (buf[bufIndex] - x > 50 && abs(Qtemp - k) > 40) {
      tft.drawLine(k, 0, k, 120, ILI9341_BLACK);
      Qtemp = k;
      RiseDetect = true;
      rise = millis();
    }

    if (x - buf[bufIndex] > 60 && RiseDetect && abs(Btemp - k) > 40) {
      long int beat = millis() - Ttemp;
      if (rise != 0) {
       long TQRS = (millis() - rise) * 3;
        if (TQRS < 200) {
          QRS = TQRS;
        }
      }
      Btemp = k;
      if (beat > 600) {
        movingAvg(60000/beat);
      }
      printQRS(QRS);
      printHR(HR[4]);
      detectStatus();
      Ttemp = millis();
      tft.drawLine(k, 0, k, 120, ILI9341_GREEN);
      RiseDetect = false;
    }else if ( millis() - Ttemp > 2000) {
      movingAvg(HR[4] / 6);
      QRS = 0;
      printQRS(QRS);
      printHR(HR[4]);
      detectStatus();
    }
  }
  xPrev = x;
  bufIndex += 1;

}

void detectStatus() {
  tft.setCursor(120, 200);
  tft.setTextSize(1);
  tft.setTextColor(ILI9341_WHITE);
  tft.print("ECG Status: ");
  tft.fillRect(180,200,140,20,ILI9341_BLACK);
  tft.setCursor(190, 200);
  tft.setTextSize(1);
  if ( HR[4] == 0) {
    tft.print("Asystole detected");
    Arrhythmia[0]++;
  }else if (HR[4] < 60) {   
     tft.print("Bradycardia detected");
     Arrhythmia[1]++;
  }else if (HR[4] > 100) {
     tft.print("Tachycardia detected");
     Arrhythmia[2]++;
  }else if (QRS > 120){
     tft.print("PVC detected");
     Arrhythmia[3]++;
  }else{
     tft.print("Normal");
     Arrhythmia[4]++;
  }
}

void ifStable() {
  if (abs(x-xPrev) > 150) {
    stable = false;
    stabilizing = true;
  }else if(stabilizing && abs(x-xPrev) < 150) {
    stable = true;
    stabilizing = false;
    //refresh = true;
    cleanScreen();
    k = 0;
    //refresh = false;
  }
  if (!stable && stabilizing) {
    //refresh = true;
    tft.fillRect(0, 0, 320, 120, ILI9341_BLUE);
    tft.setCursor(0, 0);
    tft.setTextSize(4);
    tft.setTextColor(ILI9341_RED);
    tft.print("Stablizing");
    //refresh = false;
  }
}

void movingAvg(long newData) {
   HR[HRindex] = newData;
   HR[4] = (HR[0] + HR[1] + HR[2] + HR[3])/4;
   HRindex++;
   HRindex = HRindex % 4;
   Ttemp = millis();  
}

void printHR(long HR) {
  tft.setCursor(20, 120);
  tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.setTextColor(ILI9341_WHITE);
  tft.print("HR (BPM)");
  tft.fillRect(20, 140, 80, 80, ILI9341_WHITE);
  tft.setCursor(40, 160);
  tft.setTextSize(5);
  tft.setTextColor(ILI9341_GREEN);
  tft.print(HR);
}

void printQRS(long QRS) {
  tft.setCursor(120, 120);
  tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.setTextColor(ILI9341_WHITE);
  tft.print("QRS(ms): ");
  tft.fillRect(220,120,40,20,ILI9341_BLACK);
  tft.setCursor(220, 120);
  tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.print(QRS);
}

void bluetoothSend(long data) {
  refresh = true;
  /* Command is sent when \n (\r) or println is called */
  /* AT+GATTCHAR=CharacteristicID,value */
  ble.print( F("AT+GATTCHAR=") );
  ble.print( hrmMeasureCharId );
  ble.print( F(",00-") );
  ble.println(data, HEX);
  refresh = false;
}

void writeSD() {
  // Storing 30s Data into SD card
  long int Now = millis();
  int i, j = 0;
  int maxIndex = 0;
  long maxCount = 0;
  if (Now - PrevTime >= 33000) {
    // Creating file name
    String fileNum = String(currentFile);
    String fileName = String("Data" + fileNum + ".txt");
    char charFileName[fileName.length()];
    fileName.toCharArray(charFileName, fileName.length() + 1);
    if (SD.exists(charFileName)) { // Delete the pre-existing file
      SD.remove(charFileName);     // with the desired file Name
    }
    File myFile = SD.open(charFileName, FILE_WRITE);
    String ECGstatus = "";
// !!! moderator edit -  changed i to j !!!
    for (j = 0; j < 5; i++) {
        if (Arrhythmia[j] > maxCount) {
            maxIndex = j;
            maxCount = Arrhythmia[j];
            Arrhythmia[j] = 0;
        }
    }
    if (maxIndex == 0) {
      ECGstatus = "Asystole detected";
    }else if (maxIndex == 1) {
      ECGstatus = "Bradycardia detected";
    }else if (maxIndex == 2) {
      ECGstatus = "Tachycardia detected";
    }else if (maxIndex == 3) {
      ECGstatus = "PVC detected";
    }else{
      ECGstatus = "normal";
    }
    
    if(myFile) {
      Serial.print("SD Card Printing...");
      int i;
      // Printing file header with the Initials of the author and
      // File Number and the sampling frequency
      myFile.println(String("LYW,DGP-Record" + fileNum + "-250"));
      myFile.println("ECG status: " + ECGstatus);
      for (i = 1; i <= 7500; i++) {
        myFile.print(buf[i - 1]);
        myFile.print(", ");
        if ((i%8) == 0) {
          myFile.println();
        }
      }
      myFile.println("EOF");      
    }
    myFile.close();
    Serial.println("Done");
    currentFile++;
    PrevTime = Now;
  } 
}

void readFromFile() {
  SD.begin(SD_CS);
  File root = SD.open("/");
  printDirectory(root, 0);
  tft.fillScreen(ILI9341_WHITE);
  tft.setCursor(20, 150);
  tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.setTextColor(ILI9341_BLACK);
  tft.print("Waiting for monitor input");
  SD.begin(SD_CS);
  Serial.print("Please enter file number: DATA");
  String fileNum = "-1";
  while (fileNum.toInt() <= 0 && Read){
    fileNum = Serial.readString();
    if (fileNum == "stop") {
      Read = !Read;
      screenInit();
      break;
    }
  }
  Serial.println(fileNum);
  String fileName = String("DATA" + fileNum + ".txt");
  char charFileName[fileName.length()];
  fileName.toCharArray(charFileName, fileName.length() + 1);
  File myFile = SD.open(charFileName);
  
  if (myFile) {
    int skipHeader = 0;
    int index = 0;
    // read from the file until there's nothing else in it:
    while (myFile.available()) {
      if (skipHeader < 3) {
        skipHeader++;
        myFile.parseInt();
      } else {
        String dataRead = myFile.parseInt();
        uint16_t dataSave = dataRead.toInt();
        buf[index] = dataSave;
      }
      index++;
    }
    // close the file:
    myFile.close();
    screenInit();
    k = 0;
  } else {
    // if the file didn't open, print an error:
    Serial.println("error opening file");
  }
}

void printDirectory(File root, int numTabs) {
  while (true) {
    File entry =  root.openNextFile();
    if (! entry) {
      // no more files
      break;
    }

    if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
      Serial.println(entry.name());
    } 
    entry.close();
  }
}

void bluetoothInit() {
  bool success;
  Serial.println(F("Adafruit Bluefruit Heart Rate Monitor (HRM) Example"));
  Serial.println(F("---------------------------------------------------"));

  randomSeed(micros());

  /* Initialise the module */
  Serial.print(F("Initialising the Bluefruit LE module: "));

  if ( !ble.begin(VERBOSE_MODE) )
  {
    error(F("Couldn't find Bluefruit, make sure it's in CoMmanD mode & check wiring?"));
  }
  Serial.println( F("OK!") );

  /* Perform a factory reset to make sure everything is in a known state */
  Serial.println(F("Performing a factory reset: "));
  if (! ble.factoryReset() ){
       error(F("Couldn't factory reset"));
  }

  /* Disable command echo from Bluefruit */
  ble.echo(false);

  Serial.println("Requesting Bluefruit info:");
  /* Print Bluefruit information */
  ble.info();

  // this line is particularly required for Flora, but is a good idea
  // anyways for the super long lines ahead!
  // ble.setInterCharWriteDelay(5); // 5 ms

  /* Change the device name to make it easier to find */
  Serial.println(F("Setting device name to 'Bluefruit HRM': "));

  if (! ble.sendCommandCheckOK(F("AT+GAPDEVNAME=Bluefruit HRM")) ) {
    error(F("Could not set device name?"));
  }

  /* Add the Heart Rate Service definition */
  /* Service ID should be 1 */
  Serial.println(F("Adding the Heart Rate Service definition (UUID = 0x180D): "));
  success = ble.sendCommandWithIntReply( F("AT+GATTADDSERVICE=UUID=0x180D"), &hrmServiceId);
  if (! success) {
    error(F("Could not add HRM service"));
  }

  /* Add the Heart Rate Measurement characteristic */
  /* Chars ID for Measurement should be 1 */
  Serial.println(F("Adding the Heart Rate Measurement characteristic (UUID = 0x2A37): "));
  success = ble.sendCommandWithIntReply( F("AT+GATTADDCHAR=UUID=0x2A37, PROPERTIES=0x10, MIN_LEN=2, MAX_LEN=3, VALUE=00-40"), &hrmMeasureCharId);
    if (! success) {
    error(F("Could not add HRM characteristic"));
  }

  /* Add the Body Sensor Location characteristic */
  /* Chars ID for Body should be 2 */
  Serial.println(F("Adding the Body Sensor Location characteristic (UUID = 0x2A38): "));
  success = ble.sendCommandWithIntReply( F("AT+GATTADDCHAR=UUID=0x2A38, PROPERTIES=0x02, MIN_LEN=1, VALUE=3"), &hrmLocationCharId);
    if (! success) {
    error(F("Could not add BSL characteristic"));
  }

  /* Add the Heart Rate Service to the advertising data (needed for Nordic apps to detect the service) */
  Serial.print(F("Adding Heart Rate Service UUID to the advertising payload: "));
  ble.sendCommandCheckOK( F("AT+GAPSETADVDATA=02-01-06-05-02-0d-18-0a-18") );

  /* Reset the device for the new service setting changes to take effect */
  Serial.print(F("Performing a SW reset (service changes require a reset): "));
  ble.reset();
  Serial.println();
}

static const uint8_t channel2sc1a[] = {
  5, 14, 8, 9, 13, 12, 6, 7, 15, 4,
  0, 19, 3, 21, 26, 22
};
/*
  ADC_CFG1_ADIV(2)         Divide ratio = 4 (F_BUS = 48 MHz => ADCK = 12 MHz)
  ADC_CFG1_MODE(1)         Single ended 12 bit mode
  ADC_CFG1_ADLSMP          Long sample time
*/
#define ADC_CONFIG1 (ADC_CFG1_ADIV(1) | ADC_CFG1_MODE(1) | ADC_CFG1_ADLSMP)
/*
  ADC_CFG2_MUXSEL          Select channels ADxxb
  ADC_CFG2_ADLSTS(3)       Shortest long sample time
*/
#define ADC_CONFIG2 (ADC_CFG2_MUXSEL | ADC_CFG2_ADLSTS(3))
void adcInit() {
  ADC0_CFG1 = ADC_CONFIG1;
  ADC0_CFG2 = ADC_CONFIG2;
  // Voltage ref vcc, hardware trigger, DMA
  ADC0_SC2 = ADC_SC2_REFSEL(0) | ADC_SC2_ADTRG | ADC_SC2_DMAEN;
  // Enable averaging, 4 samples
  ADC0_SC3 = ADC_SC3_AVGE | ADC_SC3_AVGS(0);
  adcCalibrate();
  Serial.println("calibrated");
  // Enable ADC interrupt, configure pin
  ADC0_SC1A = ADC_SC1_AIEN | channel2sc1a[6];
  NVIC_ENABLE_IRQ(IRQ_ADC0);
}
void adcCalibrate() {
  uint16_t sum;

  // Begin calibration
  ADC0_SC3 = ADC_SC3_CAL;
  // Wait for calibration
  while (ADC0_SC3 & ADC_SC3_CAL);
  // Plus side gain
  sum = ADC0_CLPS + ADC0_CLP4 + ADC0_CLP3 + ADC0_CLP2 + ADC0_CLP1 + ADC0_CLP0;
  sum = (sum / 2) | 0x8000;
  ADC0_PG = sum;
// Minus side gain (not used in single-ended mode)
  sum = ADC0_CLMS + ADC0_CLM4 + ADC0_CLM3 + ADC0_CLM2 + ADC0_CLM1 + ADC0_CLM0;
  sum = (sum / 2) | 0x8000;
  ADC0_MG = sum;
}
/*
  PDB_SC_TRGSEL(15)        Select software trigger
  PDB_SC_PDBEN             PDB enable
  PDB_SC_PDBIE             Interrupt enable
  PDB_SC_CONT              Continuous mode
  PDB_SC_PRESCALER(7)      Prescaler = 128
  PDB_SC_MULT(1)           Prescaler multiplication factor = 10
*/
#define PDB_CONFIG (PDB_SC_TRGSEL(15) | PDB_SC_PDBEN | PDB_SC_PDBIE \
  | PDB_SC_CONT | PDB_SC_PRESCALER(7) | PDB_SC_MULT(1))
// 48 MHz / 128 / 10 / 1 Hz = 37500
#define PDB_PERIOD (F_BUS / 128 / 10 / 1) / 250
void pdbInit() {
  // Enable PDB clock
  SIM_SCGC6 |= SIM_SCGC6_PDB;
  // Timer period
  PDB0_MOD = PDB_PERIOD;
  // Interrupt delay
  PDB0_IDLY = 0;
  // Enable pre-trigger
  PDB0_CH0C1 = PDB_CH0C1_TOS | PDB_CH0C1_EN;
  // PDB0_CH0DLY0 = 0;
  PDB0_SC = PDB_CONFIG | PDB_SC_LDOK;
  // Software trigger (reset and restart counter)
  PDB0_SC |= PDB_SC_SWTRIG;
  // Enable interrupt request
  //NVIC_ENABLE_IRQ(IRQ_PDB);
}

void adc0_isr() {
  //HighPass.input(ADC0_RA);
  LowPass.input(ADC0_RA);
  //HighPass.input(LowPass.output());
  //LowPass.input(HighPass.output());
  x = LowPass.output();
  x = x % 3500;
  if (!pause && !refresh && !Read){
      if ( k != 320) {
          k +=1;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: how is the code failing? ... instead of asking for a converion, ask for error resolution

Comment: Its ADC library

Comment: Cannot find ADC for T4, can anyone share library link thank you

Comment: I've added some details to my answer.

Comment: Thank you @DamienD for the answer, I'm trying to figuring it out how it can be done, have only 2 weeks left, purchasing another 3.6 will be a problem. 

Comment: @Rohitgupta if your sampling rate is low eg. 100 Hz and your signal processing is not very sensitive to jitter, you might get away with just analogRead() in a loop. One step up from that would be to use the continuous measurement mode without DMA. Etc.

Comment: Hey @DamienD can you tell any other teensy greater than 4 has PDB which can support this code?

Comment: No, this code will only work on a 3. If you're going for the 4, I recommend starting from scratch rather than try to port things line-by-line. You don't need a PDB to do what you want, it's just the way it was done on the 3.2. On the 4 you would probably use a QuadTimer instead. But I suspect you can get away with a simpler solution, because ECG shouldn't need a very high sampling rate .

Answer (score 4):

The Teensy 4 uses a different chip. Most of your code should be portable thanks to Teensyduino, though subtle differences could emerge.

The ADC code you're using is not portable because it accesses the hardware registers directly. You will need to rewrite that part completely for the Teensy 4. There are some libs out there (search for Teensy 4 ADC lib), but if they don't cover your needs you will have to work from the iMXRT manual.

---

A few more details: it seems like your source code is partly derived from [this university lab module](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse474/18wi/labs/l5/l5.html). What the code is doing is configure the Teensy 3's PDB (programmable delay block) to trigger ADC conversions and transfer them via DMA.

The microcontroller in the Teensy 4 does not have a PDB, so you'll have to use another method. Hard to say what is best without going deeper into the code & project; have a look [here](https://github.com/pedvide/ADC/tree/master/examples) for some examples of how to use the Teensy 4's ADC beyond what can be done with a simple `analogRead()`.

Due to the differences in hardware, this may not be a simple task. The Teensy 3.6 may be an easier option if you can find one, but it is also [lacking](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/techspecs.html) the 3.2's PGA, and I suspect (though I haven't confirmed it) that this code relies upon it.